# Is it possible to view all the contents of a namespace in c ++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, using

When you do the command:

```
using namespace std;
```

You get direct access to **all** elements of the std namespace. But suppose you want to use only the `std::cout` or `std::endl` so it would be better to use the directive:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

So you would only get the objects **you need to use** not all. 
My question is: 
is there a way to view what is added when using the command:

```
using namespace std;
```

Something like: (I know this is highly wrong.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << std;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could always look at the source code.

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ language specification that gives you this. You will need to look at the documentation for whatever C++ compiler you're using. Perhaps your C++ compiler has some compiler-specific tools that you can use to obtain this information.

Comment: The only real tool available to list what is in a namespace is the documentation of what is in that namespace.   For namespace `std`, that documentation is in the standard (across some hundreds of pages) and in various sets of reference documentation that are readily available online.   Since namespaces can be declared across multiple compilation units (and headers), the compiler may not have visibility of everything in a namespace either.

Comment: Some `IDEs` will give your a tree view of the *namespaces* and their contents. Ff you open a header file you can see everything i that file.

Comment: You could simply to lookup in source code for specific class

Comment: You could look at the output of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare that you are using `namespace std` you tell the compiler that all the functions and objects within a specific namespace are accessible without having to prefix the namespace's name.

You imported `iostream` which is actually just a header. But within this header are declared prototypes, and those are organized within namespaces (`std` in that case).

Depending of the C++ standard development libraries, the content of the file `iostream` may vary. However the implementation of the standard library is... standard.

Take a look at a source code example here: [GCC - Libstdc++ iostream](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00911_source.html)

You can see within the header the functions that are declared within the `namespace std`:

```
00043 namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
00044 {
...
00061   extern istream cin;       /// Linked to standard input
00062   extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
00063   extern ostream cerr;      /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
00064   extern ostream clog;      /// Linked to standard error (buffered)
...
00067   extern wistream wcin;     /// Linked to standard input
00068   extern wostream wcout;    /// Linked to standard output
00069   extern wostream wcerr;    /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
00070   extern wostream wclog;    /// Linked to standard error (buffered)
...
```

Note that some IDEs (Visual Studio and cons) might provide you syntactic completion allowing you to view what is within a namespace or class scope.

Answer (score 0):

The tool to see what a namespace provides is the documentation of whatever provides that namespace and the headers defining the content of the namespace.
Since headers are often highly optimised and not really for human eyes, the preferrable way is reading doucmentation.
The dcoumentation of what is inside `std` for example is available on many websites.

Looking at any other namespace, you (hopefully) get documentation and headers, too.

For "viewing" programmatically, I am afraid I have to agree with Sam.

Answer (score 0):

[Features of the C++ Standard Library are declared within the `std namespace`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)

-->
[C++ Standard Library headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)